# writing array data into a text file in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to write the array data of one of the channel into a text file. How can I do it?

I tried this

```
Mat img = imread("dog.jpg", 1);

std::ofstream fout("myfile.txt");

fout << img.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
```

but it is copying the data of all the 3 channels. I want to store the data of only one channel, let us say B[][]. Suppose I have already stored the data of all the channels separately in R[][],G[][],B[][] as shown.

```
Vec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(i, j);

B[j][i]=intensity[0];
G[j][i] = intensity[1];
R[j][i] = intensity[2];

fout << ??????????????????????;  //want to store data of Blue channel
```

Comment: how do you want to store this data? It seems that you want to save binary data but you're using `"myfile.txt"` which is a little confusing. What is the desired file format of the data?

Comment: I want to store uchar data in the text file.

Comment: I have also tried size = sizeof(B);
 
 file = fopen("myfile.txt", "wt");
 int bytes_read = fwrite(B, sizeof(unsigned char), size, file);
 fclose(file);

Comment: But again I am not getting the intensity values in text format i.e uchar values. Instead I am getting some binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mat img = imread("d:\\ImagesForTest\\cat.jpg", 1);
std::ofstream fout("myfile.txt");
vector<Mat> ch;
cv::split(img,ch);

  //  Possible formatters
  // --------------------------
  //  (matlab)      Formatter::FMT_MATLAB
  //  (python)      Formatter::FMT_PYTHON
  //  (numpy)       Formatter::FMT_NUMPY
  //  (csv)         Formatter::FMT_CSV
  //  (c)           Formatter::FMT_C 

fout << format(ch[0], Formatter::FMT_CSV); // Blue
fout << format(ch[1], Formatter::FMT_CSV); // Green
fout << format(ch[2], Formatter::FMT_CSV); // Red
```

Comment: Andrey what you said is right but I want to first store the data of a particular channel in an uchar array and then after performing some operations on it like inverting the values, I want to store the inverted values in a file.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
 {
  for (j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
  {
 
   G[j][i]=ch[0].at<uchar>(i,j);
   G[j][i]=255-G[j][i];
 
  
  }
 
 }       I tried as above and now I want to store the values of G[j][i] in a file but when i try to do fout << G; It stores some binary information but I want to store the values as text. Please explain.

Comment: You can apply your processing to matrix and get result as a matrix. Just don't use arrays of char, use matrix instead.

Comment: You can use one channel matrix with uchar element type CV_8UC1.  Matrices ch[0]-ch[2] have this element type in my code example.